# DB connection fails (System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlException)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, system.data.sqlite, sqlclient

I am programming a Weatherstation which gets the data from an API.
This works fine, but I want to store it in a database to draw a graph with it.
But my code does not seem to work. I tried debugging it and it fails on the line where I want to open the database. It runs through the line where I create the DB.

These are the failing lines:

```
databaseCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
(LocalDB)\v10.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jeroen
Laptop\Desktop\Eindopdrachten\WeatherStation\Eindopdracht\
Weather.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
databaseCon.Open();
```

**Error message in the console:**

A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

**What happens:**

I want to get the data from the API and put this into the DB for making a graph with temperatures, location and date. For this I created a database and I want to connect with it. This is where the error kicks in. I get the error from above.
When I debug that message shows up a few times(100 or so) and continues to run, without filling the database.

I hope someone here can give me some more information or can see what I do wrong.

**Update:**

*I got the following message when trying to acces the database*

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
> occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
> occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
> not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
> correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a
> Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is
> properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is
> enabled.)

I use Visual Studio 2010 with SQL server 2008.
2012 is not supported by my programming laptop.

Comment: You could start giving us some information about the error message.

Comment: Define "fails."  What indication do you have that it's not working as intended?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;.....` (`v11.0` instead of `v10.0`)

Comment: Im using Visual Studio 2010. Some information will be here soon Steve!

Comment: Obvious question but Is SQL Server Express running ?

Comment: can you access the required LocalBD instance through the Command Line or Powershell?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/

Answer (score 1):

It must be v11.0, not v10.0, and in the future there will be v12.0+, but there is no v10.0. This has nothing to do with Visual Studio 2010 or SQL Server 2008. LocalDb first came with SQL Express 2012 and is v11.0.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx

LocalDb also required as least .NET 4.02, but unfortunately the version in the registry is always v4.0.30319, even if you have earlier .NET
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/27/net-framework-4-now-supports-localdb.aspx

If possible, just upgrade to .NET 4.5

This problem can also exist if using a named instance instead of v11.0 and the program or service was ran as a different user and that user instance is still attached to the database. Unfortunately the database can take awhile to automatically detach.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is probably a permissions error of some sort.

You are creating the DB on your desktop and I would bet that SQL server doesn't have rights to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Connection to a LocalDB requires this connection string

Automatic Instance

```
 Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
                  ^^^^^
```

With a specific data file

```
 Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFileName=.......;
```

See the references on [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/)

Also, the version of the NET Framework required to connect is 4.02, you could check on

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\
```

Comment: I checked all this, but the problem is still there. Is my whole code usefull maybe?

Comment: Do you have something in the InnerException field of the main exception, sometime the real problem is indicated there. I suppose that you have installed the SQL Server bits, right? http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-localdb-setup.aspx

Comment: I will look at this in a bit. Actually, I remember that I had problems with an other database, maybe I deleted some wrong files. I will look for this also!

Comment: Hmm did not found sql server. Installing it right now. I wonder if the problems are solved when it's up!

Comment: Hmm, Some problems with SQL 2012. I will edit this post later on!